# Calculate statistics based on values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID_1,value_1,value_2,ID_2         
1,21,0,A1
1,31,5,A2
1,0,0,A3
1,21,0,A4
1,21,21,A5
2,202,0,B1
2,310,159,B2
2,0,0,B3
2,201,310,B4
2,210,214,B5
2,178,190,B6

tdf = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to compute the mean, median and mode for each of the `ID_1`

However, I would like to **exclude rows which has zeroes for both `value_1` AND `value_2`**

For ex: We will ignore/filter out row index 2 and 7.

Once, we ignore rows with zero values, we compute `mean`, `median` and `mode` **based on values from `value_1` and `value_2` for each `ID_1`. Meaning, we concatenate the values in both columns `value_1` and `value_2` and then compute the statistics**

I was trying something like belowm but it is incorrect

```
tdf = tdf[~(tdf['value_1']==0) & (tdf['value_2']==0)]  #this is incorrect logic
t1_count = tdf.groupby('ID')['value_1'].size().reset_index()
t1_values = tdf.groupby('ID')['value_1'].agg(list)
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
    ID_1    mean    mode    median
0   1   18.8    21  21.0
1   2   183.5   310 201.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need remove rows with both `0` use:

```
tdf = tdf[~((tdf['value_1']==0) & (tdf['value_2']==0))]
```

Or:

```
tdf = tdf[(tdf['value_1']!=0) | (tdf['value_2']!=0)]
```

Or:

```
tdf = tdf[tdf[['value_1','value_1']].ne(0).all(axis=1)]
```

And then:

```
df = (tdf.melt(id_vars='ID_1', 
              value_vars=['value_1','value_2'])
          .groupby('ID_1')['value'].agg(['mean','median',lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]])
          .rename(columns={'<lambda_0>':'mode'})
          .reset_index())
print (df)
   ID_1   mean  median  mode
0     1   15.0    21.0    21
1     2  197.4   201.5   310
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. but do you know how we can compute statistics based on values from both columns `value_1` and `value_2`?

Comment: I think your output is different from the expected output. We need to put the `value_1` and `value_2` values together for each `ID_1` and compute the statistics

Comment: Not as statistics for two different columns. We need to concatenate `value_1` and `value_2` and then compute `mean, median and mode`

Comment: can you help me understand what does this `lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]` do?

Comment: Meaning, how does accessing a single value in dataframe row gives us the mode?

Comment: shouldn't it be across a range of values to compute mode?

Comment: @TheGreat - if check [mode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mode.html) if same number of maximal values get multiple values (you can test it if remove `.iat[0]`). So is added `.iat[0]` for first mode instead all modes.